# Where can I host a jQuery slider/widget and iframe it?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, web, host

I have a jQuery slideshow. All its files are hosted by Dropbox. So when I put my HTML code online (fetching css and js files) it works just fine.

The problem is that the website I want to work on it's a Jimdo website and Jimdo does not support jQuery. So my only hope is to iframe my jQuery slideshow. But where will I host my widget?

**Not the files, the widget itself...**

Here's the HTML code for the jQuery slideshow / widget:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ResponsiveSlides.js &middot; Responsive jQuery slideshow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12608183/ResponsiveSlides.js-master/responsiveslides.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12608183/ResponsiveSlides.js-master/demo/demo.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12608183/ResponsiveSlides.js-master/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
            $(function () {
                // Slideshow 1
                $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
                    maxwidth: 800,
                    speed: 800
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Slideshow 1 -->
            <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
                <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPlSuCpMPhKN_P3JFKD875c_Wsd5e_Xy5OJCHYsvLZ6s24820" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnz-gglGHf9bY7P1Yu-qCFUlV9xh9pSOWFdeRPmJ3otTyWfjJw" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pastehtml](http://pastehtml.com/) and use the link it to show it in iframe